# Spring Boot MVC Converter Cannot Autowire Neo4J Data Repositories

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I'm needing to @Autowire a Spring Data Neo4J repository into a Spring MVC converter (in Spring Boot), but the MVC configuration gets started before the Data services get started. This results in an @Autowired not found problem. **How do I get the Data Services to get started before the MVC so it finds an eligible bean?**

I have a project I'm converting from XML Spring config to Spring Boot. Everything is working fine except for the MVC Converters. They are not able to @Autowire Neo4J Repository classes.

If remove the @Autowire of the Repository and hard code in a value, things work as expected with the hack. Other operations in services are using the Repositories just fine. It seems the MVC config is getting started before the Neo4J plumbing can get started and then can't find the right components to tie into. I've looked, but I can't figure out how to get the data config to start before the MVC config.

Here's my base config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Toyfiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Toyfiles.class, args);
    }
}
```

My MVC Config:

```
@Configuration
public class MVCBeans extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private StringToBrand stringToBrand;

@Autowired
private BrandToString brandToString;

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(stringToBrand);
    registry.addConverter(brandToString);
    super.addFormatters(registry);
}
```

}

The offending Converter:

```
@Component
public class StringToBrand implements Converter<String, Brand> {
    @Autowired
    BrandRepository brandRepository;

    @Override
    public Brand convert(String s) {
        return brandRepository.findBrandByName(s);
    }
}
```

The Data config:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("localEmbeddedDBServer")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.toyfiles.dataservices.")
public class LocalDBConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public LocalDBConfig() {
        setBasePackage("com.toyfiles");
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("target/graph.db");
    }
}
```

And the Repository:

```
public interface BrandRepository extends GraphRepository<Brand> {

    @Query(value = "MATCH (brand:Brand {name:{0}})-[:PART_OF]->line RETURN line")
    public List<Line> getLinesForBrand(String name);

    @Query(value = "MATCH (brand:Brand {name:{0}}) DELETE brand")
    public void deleteBrandByName(String name);

    public Brand findBrandByName(String name);
}
```

The "interesting" part of the Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brandRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/toyfiles/configuration/LocalDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/toyfiles/configuration/LocalDBConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d49af10: startup date [Mon Sep 29 09:48:25 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/toyfiles/configuration/LocalDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/toyfiles/configuration/LocalDBConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d49af10: startup date [Mon Sep 29 09:48:25 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/toyfiles/configuration/LocalDBConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d49af10: startup date [Mon Sep 29 09:48:25 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 138 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/toyfiles/configuration/LocalDBConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d49af10: startup date [Mon Sep 29 09:48:25 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:288)
    at com.toyfiles.configuration.LocalDBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$321222c6.mappingInfrastructure(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate(Neo4jConfiguration.java:135)
    at com.toyfiles.configuration.LocalDBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$321222c6.CGLIB$neo4jTemplate$23(<generated>)
    at com.toyfiles.configuration.LocalDBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$321222c6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12e74a61.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at com.toyfiles.configuration.LocalDBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$321222c6.neo4jTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d49af10: startup date [Mon Sep 29 09:48:25 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.RelationshipInfo.<init>(RelationshipInfo.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.RelationshipInfo.fromField(RelationshipInfo.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jPersistentPropertyImpl.extractRelationshipInfo(Neo4JPersistentPropertyImpl.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jPersistentPropertyImpl.<init>(Neo4JPersistentPropertyImpl.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(Neo4jMappingContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(Neo4jMappingContext.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.RelationshipInfo.<init>(RelationshipInfo.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.RelationshipInfo.fromField(RelationshipInfo.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jPersistentPropertyImpl.extractRelationshipInfo(Neo4JPersistentPropertyImpl.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jPersistentPropertyImpl.<init>(Neo4JPersistentPropertyImpl.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(Neo4jMappingContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(Neo4jMappingContext.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:427)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:295)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.initialize(Neo4jMappingContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 160 more
```

Comment: Can you explicitly state your question at the top of your post to make it easier for others to work out what you are asking. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used an @Lazy annotation for the repository to delay the reference to the repository since the repository was getting started correctly later in the startup. This allowed the repository reference to be delayed until it was needed and available.

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
BrandRepository brandRepository;
```

Comment: This works but does not seem like an elegant solution. I'd be interested to hear if you found something cleaner